# Animation triggered on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

**I would like to animate this div so when i click the "Show More" button the height changes depending on the height of the text. I have problems with the animations 'cuz it's triggered only on the second click on the "Show More" button. Any idea please??**

This is the html file :

```
<div class="col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="testimonial">
        <h5>John P.</h5>
            <div id="div1" class="comment-container" ng-class="{show1:show1}">
<p>“Yes very good experience, the tekker came on time and known how to do his job, very pleased with the service.“
                </p>
            </div>

            <button id="comm1" class="btn btn-info1 btn-xs" style="cursor: pointer;  margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 12px; border-radius: 10px;"
                    ng-click="homeCtrl.animateComment();" ng-show="!show1">Show more
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-info2 btn-xs" style="cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 12px; border-radius: 10px;"
                    ng-click="show1 = false;" ng-show="show1">Show less
             </button>
         </div>

         <img class="triunghi" src="/img/triunghi.png">
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
.comment-container  {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 52px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: -12px;
}
.show-more{
    cursor: pointer;  margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.show-less{
    cursor: pointer; margin-bottom: 12px;
}
.show1 {
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
}
.show2 {
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
}
.show3 {
    overflow: visible;
    height: auto;
}
```

And this is the javascript and jquery:

```
function animateComment() {
        $scope.show1 = true;
        $("#comm1").click(function(){
            $("#div1").animate({
                left: '250px',
                opacity: '0.5',
                height: '150px'
            },2000);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.click()` method call in your function; that is for attaching event handlers, not calling them. Try this:

```
function animateComment() {
    $scope.show1 = true;
    $("#div1").animate({
        left: '250px',
        opacity: '0.5',
        height: '150px'
    }, 2000);
}
```